# How to get the NumPad layout

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

I need the layout for numpad on the keyboard. I got most of it, the only problem I am having is that the "enter" button is supposed to be till the bottom. But when I use the Panel p4 and I set it to SOUTH the "enter" button does not reach the bottom. Here is the code.

This is what it look like

[image]

This is what I wanted

[image]

```
public class NumPad extends Applet
{   
  public void init() {
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  Panel p1 = new Panel();
  p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
  p1.add(new Button("Num"));
  p1.add(new Button("/"));
  p1.add(new Button("*"));
  p1.add(new Button("-"));
  add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

  Panel p2 = new Panel();
  p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0));
  p2.add(new Button("7"));
  p2.add(new Button("8"));
  p2.add(new Button("9"));
  p2.add(new Button("4"));
  p2.add(new Button("5"));
  p2.add(new Button("6"));
  p2.add(new Button("1"));
  p2.add(new Button("2"));
  p2.add(new Button("3"));
  add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);      

  Panel p4 = new Panel();
  p4.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 30, 40));
  p4.add(new Button("0"));
  p4.add(new Button("."));
  add(p4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);      

  Panel p3 = new Panel();
  p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));
  p3.add(new Button("+"));
  p3.add(new Button("Enter"));
  add(p3, BorderLayout.EAST);      
 }
}
```

Comment: CAn you add picture or so to see how it look like and how do you want it?

Comment: i dont have 20 rep. sorry but here is the link of what it should look like. http://i.imgur.com/bjdLRfj.png  , and this is what i have http://i.imgur.com/6XIUNEh.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to re-arrange everything, you can simlpy nest `p2` and `p4` into another `JPanel`  and add that new panel in the center. As long as you don't add anything in the `SOUTH` of the "main" panel, you are good to go.

By the way, don't use awt components, go directly for the Swing ones. This will save you lot of time and avoid troubling behaviour (consider extending `JApplet` instead of `Applet`)

See this small example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class NumPad extends JPanel {
    public NumPad() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel top = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        top.add(new JButton("Num"));
        top.add(new JButton("/"));
        top.add(new JButton("*"));
        top.add(new JButton("-"));
        add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel p2p4 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 0));
        p2.add(new JButton("7"));
        p2.add(new JButton("8"));
        p2.add(new JButton("9"));
        p2.add(new JButton("4"));
        p2.add(new JButton("5"));
        p2.add(new JButton("6"));
        p2.add(new JButton("1"));
        p2.add(new JButton("2"));
        p2.add(new JButton("3"));
        p2p4.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
        p4.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 30, 40));
        p4.add(new JButton("0"));
        p4.add(new JButton("."));
        p2p4.add(p4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(p2p4);
        JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
        p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));
        p3.add(new JButton("+"));
        p3.add(new JButton("Enter"));
        add(p3, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame(NumPad.class.getSimpleName());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                NumPad numPad = new NumPad();
                frame.add(numPad);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: When I do this the center dissapears for some reason

Comment: @FJam Are you sure that you don't add twice something to the Center? If you run the exact code I have provided, does the issue still occurs? If not, then you probably have some kind of mistake in your code and you should try to find out how your code differs from mine.

Answer (score 0):

That's just how BorderLayout works.  `BorderLayout.EAST` does not extend to the bottom.

[image]

Try a [different layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) or rearranging your components in a different way.  See this example:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

setLayout(new BorderLayout());

Panel p1 = new Panel();
p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
p1.add(new Button("Num"));
p1.add(new Button("/"));
p1.add(new Button("*"));
panel.add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

Panel p2 = new Panel();
p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0));
p2.add(new Button("7"));
p2.add(new Button("8"));
p2.add(new Button("9"));
p2.add(new Button("4"));
p2.add(new Button("5"));
p2.add(new Button("6"));
p2.add(new Button("1"));
p2.add(new Button("2"));
p2.add(new Button("3"));
panel.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

Panel p4 = new Panel();
p4.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 30, 40));
p4.add(new Button("0"));
p4.add(new Button("."));
panel.add(p4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

Panel p3 = new Panel();
p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0));
p3.add(new Button("-"));
p3.add(new Button("+"));
p3.add(new Button("Enter"));

add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(p3, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Comment: @FJam You should be able to do it with some combination of BorderLayout and GridLayout.  See the couple of examples already on this page.